# "No module named" error for modules in one folder and valid PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following structure in my project:

```
Python-auto-tests
    Business Layer
        Yandex
            __init__.py
            Authorization.py
            Yandex_requests.py
    Documents
    venv
```

In "Authorization.py" file I have only 1 method

In "Yandex_requests.py" I trying to import "Authorization.py" module:

```
import Authorization
```

But I get following error:

```
"No module" named Authorization
```

My PATHONPATH environment variable is set to project path:

```
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests
```

Also I check my sys.path and it looks fine, my folders are here:

```
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\Business Layer\Yandex\Yandex_requests.py"
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\Business Layer\Yandex
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests
C:\Users\anduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip
C:\Users\anduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs
C:\Users\anduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib
C:\Users\anduser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\venv
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\venv\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg
C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg
```

Can you help me solve this issue? I just can't understand why Python doesn't see my module.

In the official Python documentation there is example how to import module from the same folder and I do the same.

Comment: What are the contents of your \_\_init\_\_.py?

Comment: Its empty. And as I know I don't need to have __init__.py file at all to import module in the same folder

Comment: Your `PYTHONPATH` is `C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests`, but you're trying to import a module from `C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests\Business Layer\Yandex`.  Why do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here. Let's tackle the one you are aware of first.

You say you have set `PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\anduser\Python-auto-tests`. As such, any imports you make must be relative to that path. For example, instead of `import Authorization`, you have to do `from Business Layer.Yandex import Authorization`.

Your second problem, and I think you are unaware of it, is `Business Layer`. Using default import methods, Python does not handle spaces in directory of module names. (Note that it also does not handle hyphens and several other special characters). You should change that folder to something like `BusinessLayer` or `Business_Layer`. Refer to [Package and Module Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) from the PEP8 -- Style Guide for Python Code for more information on naming conventions for different Python constructs.

Ultimately, as long as your `PYTHONPATH` remains the same, the import should be written as something like `from BusinessLayer.Yandex import Authorization`.

Comment: Thanks, I also added value stored in PATH (environment variable) to PYTHONPATH together with my project to make it works